# sh: 1: python: not found when execute python script from php

Tags: python, php, python-2.7, conda, miniconda

I'm tring to execute a python script call from php with the command below:

```
$output = shell_exec('python /var/www/html/sna/server/userManagement.py '. $user.' '. $pass .' \''.$action.'\' 2>&1');
```

But when I execute it I get this

```
sh: 1: python: not found
```

But python is correctly installed in my env.

If I digit

```
type -a python
```

I get the path of python in this env like below (not sure because they are two)

```
python is /home/leonardo/miniconda2/bin/python
python is /home/leonardo/miniconda2/envs/sna/bin/python
```

At the very beginning of the python script I have include

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

But I recieve always the same error. How can I solve ?

---

EDIT

I tried to add python path to the `$PATH` with command

```
export $PATH:/home/leonardo/miniconda2/envs/sna/bin/python
```

But I get the same error anywhay

Answer (score 0):

Your binary is not in the PATH for the webservers user account.

PHP inherits the PATH from Apache. And most distros set a fairly restrained:

```
SetEnv PATH /bin:/usr/bin
```

Either change that, or [`putenv()`](http://php.net/putenv) in PHP, or use absolute paths instead.

Comment: I tried to add `home/leonardo/miniconda2/envs/sna/bin/python` with this command `export PATH=$PATH:/home/leonardo/miniconda2/envs/sna/bin/python` but I continue to get the same error

Comment: [How does the path environment variable work in Linux?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/77898) → specifically where it says "directory"

Comment: [Setting Apache2 PATH environment variable](//serverfault.com/q/151328) (preempting more followup questions)